# JSF file upload on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, file-upload

I'm trying to have a file upload element in my JSF over Google App Engine.
I have browsed the web for several alternatives but none seem to work with GAE.

I was able to do so using JSP and servlet with BlobstoreService but couldn't find a way to make it working with JSF.

As a workaround I was trying to see if there is a way to include a JSP within a JSF but I guess this isn't doable as well.

Would be thankful to get a working example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First get library http://code.google.com/p/gmultipart/ and add to your project.
And than override class org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter (just put in your src).
There is code of class org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter:

```
package org.primefaces.webapp.filter;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
    import org.gmr.web.multipart.GFileItemFactory;
    import org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest;

    public class FileUploadFilter implements Filter {

        private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileUploadFilter.class.getName());

        private final static String THRESHOLD_SIZE_PARAM = "thresholdSize";

        private final static String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PARAM = "uploadDirectory";

        private String thresholdSize;

        private String uploadDir;

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            thresholdSize = filterConfig.getInitParameter(THRESHOLD_SIZE_PARAM);
            uploadDir = filterConfig.getInitParameter(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PARAM);

            if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                logger.fine("FileUploadFilter initiated successfully");
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpServletRequest);

            if(isMultipart) {
                if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                    logger.fine("Parsing file upload request");

                //start change
                FileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new GFileItemFactory(); 
               /* if(thresholdSize != null) {
                    diskFileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(Integer.valueOf(thresholdSize));
                }
                if(uploadDir != null) {
                    diskFileItemFactory.setRepository(new File(uploadDir));
                }*/
                //end change

                ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
                MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(httpServletRequest, servletFileUpload);

                if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                    logger.fine("File upload request parsed succesfully, continuing with filter chain with a wrapped multipart request");

                filterChain.doFilter(multipartRequest, response);
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }

        public void destroy() {
            if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                logger.fine("Destroying FileUploadFilter");
        }

    }
```

In managed bean write method like:

```
 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

    try {
        String blobKey = BlobUtils.uploadImageToBlobStore(uploadedFile.getContentType(), uploadedFile.getFileName(), uploadedFile.getContents());
        this.iconKey = blobKey;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Ошибка при попытке загрузить файл в blob-хранилище", e);
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Ошибка при попытке загрузить файл", event.getFile().getFileName() + " не загружен!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        return;
    }

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Успешно.", event.getFile().getFileName() + " загружен.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

}
```

And that all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , I think that whatever you are doing with JSP should eventually work with JSF as well..

BUT,

If you are looking for a file upload component for JSF , that works on GAE ,

take a look at the [PrimeFaces FileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadAuto.jsf;jsessionid=B9935B5E4C2A60BA74F25F4A23334EB5)

Here is another link that got an explanation on what to do in order it to work on GAE :[Primefaces File Upload Filter](http://davebarber.blog.com/2010/10/15/jsf-2-0-on-google-app-engine/)

(haven't tried it myself...)